# A special case of implicit differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Given $f(x)=log(1+x^2)-log(1+(x-\delta_1)^2)$ and $g(x)=log(1+x^2)-log(1+(x-\delta_2)^2)$ ,is there any way to calculate $\frac{df(x)}{dg(x)}$ taking $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ as fixed numbers?

Comment: What is the issue with taking $f'/g'$?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe 
$$\frac{df}{dg}=\frac{\frac{df}{dx}}{\frac{dg}{dx}}$$ ?